# How to Make Table use FPDF

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I am trying to insert a table into a PDF document using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/), the output I am trying to achieve is this:-

[image]

This is the code I have so far:-

```
$pdf->Cell(10,5,'No',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'Name',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(90,5,'Hobby',1,1,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(10,5,'',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Hobby A',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Hobby B',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Hobby B',1,1,'C',0);
```

but it gives the following output:-

[image]

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: put some code here to investigate further. have you faced any problem while try to create pdf?

Comment: Thank vascowhite sorry My Language Is Bad

Comment: Try like this:
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'No','LTR',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,'Name','LTR',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(90,5,'Hobby',1,1,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(10,5,'','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Hobby A',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Hobby B',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Hobby B',1,1,'C',0);

Comment: the attribute next to the text is for adjusting the cell borders..

Comment: Thank You  Prasath Albert. Your answer is perfect